# FreeBSD extract data from log

Tags: bash, unix, sh, freebsd

I am writing a script to get some results from a log, that shows the IP address and the username that accessed the file. The normal logs looks like this:

```
Aug  7 06:32:36 servername Apache2.4: NR443123123: client=ClientsISPname.net[192.168.1.2], Auth=LOGIN, username=MyUserName
```

I am using this to grep the IP and the username:

```
grep 'username=' /var/log/mylog | grep ^[0-9,A-Z] | awk '{print $7 $9}'
```

And it is giving me the result I need, but how can I have only the specific columns shown after this, the current results look like this:

```
client=ClientsISPname.net[192.168.1.2], username=MyUserName
client=ClientsISPname.net[192.168.1.132], username=MyUserName1
client=ClientsISPname.net[192.168.1.5], username=MyUserName2
client=ClientsISPname.net[192.168.1.95], username=MyUserName3
```

All I want is, when results show, I want the to show only the IP address and the username like this:

```
192.169.1.2, MyUsername
192.168.1.132, MyUsername1
192.168.1.5, MyUserName2
192.168.1.95, MyUserName3
```

I've tried many options but I was not able to get the result as per my needs.

Comment: `sh` and `bash` are not the same, but this question has both tags. Since FreeBSD does not have `bash` installed by default, did you really mean that tag?

Comment: I have bash installed, and the line of code will work on both.

Comment: The question is, will a solution that only works in `bash` be acceptable, or do you require a POSIX-compliant solution that will work with any compliant `sh`?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It can be bash or sh.

Comment: For those of you not familiar with FreeBSD, `grep` and `awk` are *not* the GNU versions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one line with awk;

```
awk '/username=/ {match($7, "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"); A=substr($7, RSTART, RLENGTH); split($9, B, "="); print(A, B[1]);}' /var/log/mylog
```

Formatting the `awk` program nicely

```
/username=/ {match($7, "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+");
             A=substr($7, RSTART, RLENGTH);
             split($9, B, "=");
             print(A, B[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your awk component to include a few splits.

```
{
split($7,partA,']');
split(partA[1],ipaddr,'[');
split($9, partB,'=');
printf("%s, %s\n", ipaddr[1], partB[1]);
}
```

Probably best to save this in a file and call it with awk -f filename

Comment: I am using Roland Smith's for now, will give it a try this one latter and let you know the results.

Comment: Rolands edited answer is more holistic solution (I had trouble reading the original 1 line solution). I have no issue with you acceping his answer. The use of match, RSTART and RLENGHT make it much more readable, instead of splitting a split.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am new to FreeBSD and I was not able to make your solution work! :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use perl:

```
cat /var/log/mylog | perl -e 'while (<>) {print $1.", ".$2."\n" if $_ =~ m/\[(.+?)\].*?username=(.+)/}'
```

Comment: To improve your answer, explain what the above does so less experienced users can also learn something.